# print marigin not set in second page

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private StringReader myReader;

private void printToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
printDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
string strText = this.richTextBox1.Text;
myReader = new StringReader(strText);
if (printDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{

printDocument1.Print();
}
}

private void printPrieviewToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
string strText = this.richTextBox1.Text;//read text for richtextbox
myReader = new StringReader(strText);
printPreviewDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();
}

private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
string line = null;
Font printFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman", 8, FontStyle.Regular);
SolidBrush myBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
float linesPerPage = 0;
float topMargin = 590;
float yPosition = 590;
int count = 0;
float leftMargin = 70;

linesPerPage = e.MarginBounds.Height / printFont.GetHeight(e.Graphics);
while (count < linesPerPage && ((line = myReader.ReadLine()) != null))
{
if (count == 0)
{
yPosition = 590;
topMargin = 590;
}
else
{
yPosition = 100;
topMargin = 100;
}
yPosition = topMargin + (count * printFont.GetHeight(e.Graphics));
e.Graphics.DrawString(line, printFont, myBrush, leftMargin, yPosition, new StringFormat());
count++;
}
if (line != null)
{
e.HasMorePages = true;

}
else
{
e.HasMorePages = false;
myBrush.Dispose();
}
}
}
}
```

please where is my mistake.i want to print first page is top marigin is 590,and if more pages second page should be print top marigin is 100.
above given code is printing is ok but print marigin is not solved
help me the corection.

Comment: anybody solve this one .i stuck here

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printing Multiple pages margin not set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26293174/printing-multiple-pages-margin-not-set)

Comment: @BerndLinde actually, strictly speaking, that question is a duplicate of this one.

Comment: That is correct yes, but that one has a bit more detail in it than this one atm, hence why I did it that way around to try and keep the one with the most info :)

Answer (score 0):

You are setting top margin based on `count` but `count` is not a page count, it is a line count.  you need to keep a page count and use that.

Answer (score 0):

Use a field to hold if it's the first page, remember to set it to `true` before calling `printDocument1_PrintPage` e.g:

```
bool Isfirstpage = true;

private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
///.....

   if (count == 0 && Isfirstpage)
   {
     yPosition = 590;
     topMargin = 590;
     Isfirstpage = false;
   }

///....
```

Comment: ,Not Solved ,if i can change above given it will start top margin 100 for all pages

Comment: if i enters single line text then it will start 590

Comment: Please coluld anybody help?