# Printing Multiple pages margin not set

Tags: c#, winforms

Could anybody help solve this problem?

[image]

```css
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;


namespace notepad_demo
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private StringReader myReader;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void printToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            printDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
            string strText = this.richTextBox1.Text;
            myReader = new StringReader(strText);
            if (printDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {

                printDocument1.Print();
            }
        }

        private void printPrieviewToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string strText = this.richTextBox1.Text;//read text for richtextbox
            myReader = new StringReader(strText);
            printPreviewDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
            printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();


        }

        private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {

            string strDisplay = "Header";
            System.Drawing.Font fntString = new Font("Times New Roman", 28, FontStyle.Bold);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(strDisplay, fntString, Brushes.Black, 100, 100);
            string strDisplay1 = "Company name";
            System.Drawing.Font fntString1 = new Font("Times New Roman", 28, FontStyle.Bold);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(strDisplay1, fntString1, Brushes.Black, 100, 150);

            float linesPerPage = 0;
            float yPosition = 590;
            int count = 0;
            float leftMargin = 70;
            float topMargin = 590;
            string line = null;
            Font printFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman", 8, FontStyle.Regular);
            SolidBrush myBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);               
            linesPerPage = e.MarginBounds.Height / printFont.GetHeight(e.Graphics);
            while (count < linesPerPage && ((line = myReader.ReadLine()) != null))
            {
                yPosition = topMargin + (count * printFont.GetHeight(e.Graphics));
                e.Graphics.DrawString(line, printFont, myBrush, leftMargin, yPosition, new StringFormat());
                count++;
            }

            if (line != null)
            {
                e.HasMorePages = true;

            }
            else
            {
                e.HasMorePages = false;

            }
            myBrush.Dispose();
        }
    }    
}
```

In the attached image, the first page is ok but the 2nd, 3rd and 4th pages are also beginning the same as per the first page.
I want the header and company name only on the first page and the `RichTextBox.text`` is printed on the second page, at top margin.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @Varta, as asked in your question about the same topic [yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26279404): What reporting module are you using? Are you drawing all the pages on your own?

Comment: @Bernd Linde,i want like ref image.

Comment: @Varta, did you try the recommendation that Hans Passant gave on your question from yesterday?

Comment: I don't see where you process page number (as @BerndLinde already spotted). It looks like for **all** pages you output header. While there should be a condition like `if(currentPage == 0) { /* header */ }`.

Comment: i tried but not solved.

Comment: What did you try? Amend your question with the code that you tried. Show us and we could direct you into the right direction.

Comment: i want firstpage print as per given image like header,company name and below textbox text,if textbox text more than one pages then second page should be without header and company name and only textbox text to be printed.this is what i want.i could not solve this problem.anybody help me the correct code and edit the code

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the problem of your headers printing on each page, follow the advice given to you by `Hans Passant` in the comments section, on your question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26279404).

In short it is creating a class variable called `pageCount`, setting that to 0 when you begin printing and incrementing it with each page printed.
The section that is writing your header section to your pages, should then be encapsulated within a conditional statement that will not be executed when you are printing on anything other than the first page.

To address the second issue of your text being printed very far down the page even when on the second page, that is because you are initializing your `topMargin` variable always to 590 inside the `PagePrint` event.

What you should be doing is initializing it to the top of the page (where the headers are printed) and then adjusting it according to what page you are currently printing.
Eg. for the first page print the headers from the top margin and incrementing the `topMargin` variable as you print the different headers and labels. Then when you reach your second page, you just increment your `topMargin` variable with the height of each label/line that you are printing (as what you are currently doing inside your loop).

You already have the idea of this with your variable `yPosition`, you just need to fully implement it for all things that you are printing, and not just the labels.

Comment: ,Thanks for your prompt suggesstion.but iam not able to do solve this problem of my self,so please help with code so i can understand easily.Thanks

Comment: I am sorry, but I am not going to write your code for you. It has been less than 10 minutes since I posted my answer, not enough time to properly implement and try and resolve the issues with what was suggested by myself and others.